# How to do enumerateObjectsUsingBlock-like stuff with JSONModelArray?

Tags: ios, jsonmodel

I use [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) to hold my app datasource, and use `-(id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array modelClass:(Class)cls` generated an JSONModelArray, now I want to do some search stuff like `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method does. But I found that `JSONModelArray` is not inherited from `NSArray`.

So, how can I do this?

Comment: As it says, it's another object which is constructed with an array. Since this is an external library modifying the original code is not a good idea as well. Just try to implement a simple category for the base class. It will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [BWJSONMatcher](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher) to convert json string to a NSArray.

For example, your json string seems like :

```
[{"name":"Arron","age":20,"grade":2},{"name":"Burrows","age":21,"grade":2}]
```

All you have to do is declare your own data model:

```
@interface Student : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger age;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger grade;

@end
```

[BWJSONMatcher](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher) will help you convert it to a NSArray in a very neat way:

```
NSArray *students = [BWJSONMatcher matchJSON:jsonString withClass:[Student class]];
```